# Initializing a custom UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, ipad, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom `UICollectionViewCell` that has a custom background view which is drawn using one of several colour schemes.  The colour scheme for the background view is set in my custom initializer `-(id)initWithFrame:andColourPalette:` for the View.

I have a similar custom initialiser in my `UICustomViewCell` subclass but I can't figure out how to call this initialiser when I am setting up the cell in `cellForItemAtIndexPath:`

Can anyone help me do this?  Or offer alternative solution for passing this Dictionary of colours into the Cell to pass on to the subView?

**EDIT to show more detail:**

This is what I have in my UICollectionView VC:

In ViewWillAppear:

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[OPOLawCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CELL_ID];
self.colourPalette = [OPOColourPalette greenyColourPalette];
```

In cellForItemAtIndexPath:

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell          = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CELL_ID forIndexPath:indexPath];
OPOLawCollectionViewCell *lawCell   = (OPOLawCollectionViewCell *)cell;

MainLevel *level                    = self.collectionData[indexPath.row];
lawCell.delegate                    = self;
lawCell.colourPalette               = self.colourPalette;
```

In my Custom UICollectionViewCell

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        // get background view
        OPOLawBook *lawBookView = [[OPOLawBook alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 265) andColourPalette:self.colourPalette];
```

But that doesn't work - I guess because the propertys are not set up.

If I change the last line to this, then it works fine:

```
    OPOLawBook *lawBookView = [[OPOLawBook alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 265) andColourPalette:[OPOColorPalette greenyColorPalette]];
```

So i guess I need to use a custom intialiser here but I cant figure out how to call it , or from where...

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yuo have to register your customCells in collectionView:

```
[self.collectionView_ registerClass:[YourCustomClass class]
        forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
```

And then in your method `cellForItemAtIndexPath`:

```
 YourCustomClass *cell = (YourCustomClass *)[collectionView 
         dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

It is done because collectionView might have 1000 cells and 10 visible. You don't keep all of them initialized and reuse when possible.

**EDIT**

You should set `colorPaletter` after you deque the reusable cell. Think of it as a container which can hold any color. You need to determine (by indexpath) what color to paint.

Comment: I'm doing this already, but I need to tell the cell what colour to draw the background graphics.  If I put a property on the Cell for colourPalette and then set this in cellForItemAtIndexPath: it doesn't work because the property is not set up before the cell draws it's background.  So I think I need to override the initWithFrame: so it uses my initWithFrame:andColourPalette: method.

Comment: you shouldn't make anything bound to index of cell in initialization. You need to be able to make these customizations after dequeueing the cell.

Comment: I don't really need it to be bound to the index of the cell.  Just that if the cell is called from this collectionView it needs to be a particular colour... If it is called from a different CollectionView it needs to be another colour.

Comment: Tala, thanks for trying but that sounds like what I am doing.  I don;t want the cells to be different colours, I want them all the same.  I just wanted to use the same cell class in a different collection view on a different ViewController but have them all a different colour

Comment: I think I am just going to have to use several UICollectionViewCell subclasses until I find out how to pass these values into the initialiser.

Comment: what makes a problem to set color after dequeueing the cell?

Comment: My error!!!  I was using the wrong name somewhere, an old version of the backgroundView that I had stopped using but forgotten to remove the variable...  It was working all along!!  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't do below if your custom cell is in the `Storyboard`,

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[OPOLawCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CELL_ID];
```

Because `Storyboard` take responsibility to register `Cell_ID` own.
Now, It will conflict to be generated invalid Cell if you use both.

Answer (score 2):

Way off, every answer.  The questioner is looking for a way to   uniquely identify each cell upon initialization, which happens prior to dequeuing a cell, and prior to a cell's access to its index path property.

The only way to do this is to assign a unique reuse identifier to every cell based on what the index path value will be (assuming you will know what that will be—and, in your case, you will); then, when dequeuing the cell, use the index path to find the cell with the corresponding reuse identifier.

Does this negates the purpose of reuse identifiers? Absolutely not. You'll be reusing that cell every time you need to use it again. Reuse identifiers were not meant to limit you to a cookie-cutter cell for every cell in your collection view; they are also intended to be "unique use" identifiers.