# Init method for custom UICollectionViewCell doesn't fired

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have `UICollectionView` that use custom `UICollectionViewCell` class called `ClaimInfoCell`. I want to fire its init method by overriding `initWithCoder:` but this method doesn't fired.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder
{
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
    {
        // Do something

    }
    return self;
}
```

I checked in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` and everything is fine. NSLog-ing that cell, and it was the `ClaimInfoCell`'s instance.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ClaimInfoCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"claimInfoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

Already followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406186/initializing-a-custom-uicollectionviewcell?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252912/use-custom-init-method-when-programmaticly-creating-a-uicollectionview) answer, but I can't find the right that fits on mine.

I use storyboard and customize that cell on its collection view directly. So how I should declare my custom init method my cell? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `initWithCoder` is only called when using NSKeyedArchiving, you should just use `init` or `initWithFrame`

Comment: @Fonix both of them doesnt fired too

Comment: try `awakeFromNib` then instead

Comment: I am using storyboard and doesnt use any nib anymore. Can I use `awakeFromNib` ? @Fonix

Comment: just call your own custom init method from inside `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` after you dequeue the cell (which is probably a more correct way of going about it)

Comment: i think that method still gets called even if storyboard, but i would go with my previous suggestion anyway

Comment: How to call my init method from there?

Comment: `[cell myInitMethod];` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104365/discussion-between-sonic-master-and-fonix).

Comment: i cant, proxy at work blocks the chat from SO. but i think this discussion should be done anyway

Comment: Thank you anyway. I just wondering if there is any elegant method to do that. Not by calling its init method manually.

Comment: You can also override `prepareForReuse`.